# Multiple Laravel Site conflicting in Apache with MSSql and Redis on Apache server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, apache, redis

I have two Laravel Applications hosted on the same Server.

For Example. dev.example.com and staging.example.com
Both sites provide APIs that are accessed by VUEJS sites devfh.example.com and stagingfh.example.com.
Both these sites work well, however, occasionally/randomly we get staging data in dev site and dev data in a staging site.

We are using the following technology stack:

- Apache 3.2.2.2
- PHP 7.3.12
- AWS RDS for MSSQL (Two DB dev and staging on the same instance)
- Redis for storing session cache (We tried disabling Redis cache for
  dev site still the problem persists).

I feel like this could be caching issues either on Apache, Redis, or MSSql Side or maybe PHP OpCode cache not sure.

We are not sure how to debug this problem further.

### Apache vHost Settings

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName stagingfh.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/staging/frontend/dist"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/staging/frontend/dist/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName staging.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/staging/backend/public"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/staging/backend/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName devfh.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/staging/development/dist"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/staging/development/dist/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.corigami.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/staging/development/public"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/staging/development/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on the server setup and how the site is deployed? Is it deployed manually or automated? Is it possible the Vue code is being compiled for one API but deployed to the wrong domain? The sessions should be separate by default, and I don't think browser caching would be an issue if the domains are set correctly, but maybe try a hard refresh in the browser when this happens to see if that might identify the issue?

Comment: @Spudly All four sites are configured in apache virtual host, both VueJs sites are compiled separately, the conflict occurs randomly, say when we are accessing site it is working we navigate to another page we get other site data, we navigate again and we get correct site data

Comment: @Spudly Site is hosted on AWS EC2 Windows server, with tech stack as defined in question

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a browser caching issue if it resolves itself while navigating between pages.

Are you using Mix to compile the Vue code? Make sure you are using `version()` to prevent caching issues where shared scripts might conflict with each other.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .version();
```

If that doesn't work, you can also try running these commands to clear Laravel cache.

```
php artisan clear-compile
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: We are not using Mix, our Vue Application is outside laravel

Comment: Also, browser cache is not a question, because we are facing this issue also for people who never used dev site

Comment: Why do you recommend `cache:clear` ? What if you truncate the whole redis instance of the @DharmeshCorigami ?

Comment: @Ersoy will try disabling Redis for both the sites, I did disabled it for one, but still had issues

Comment: @DharmeshCorigami I'm confused why the issue would happen periodically or resolve on its own if this was a config or caching issue on the server. I don't work with Windows machines and we use separate EC2 instances for different environments, but one thing to double check would be when caching config make sure you're not using env() outside of the config file. That data can be cached, but I don't think it would change back and forth. You'd be running into different errors. If this is an issue with the Laravel APIs, maybe try reproducing in Postman to confirm and try to debug it with logging.

Comment: @Spudly We figured out the issue, it is actually .env file that is creating the problem for Apache in windows. This comment helped me figure this out https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19454#issuecomment-411059425

Comment: @DharmeshCorigami I would have thought you'd be running into other conflicts and errors with cached .env variables running on different environments, but glad to hear you got it figured out.